# FOSJsRouting: Routing.generate not working on Android devices

Tags: javascript, symfony, url-routing

In my Symfony2 project I use routing within an event listener. On my desktop everything works fine, but NOT on Android devices. How can I make my code work also for Android?

Here comes my code:

```
$('.my-links a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var setActive = {
                user: $(this).data('user')
            };

            console.log('on android code gets processed only until here, but not beyond');

            $.get(Routing.generate('_my_route', setActive, true)).success(function () {
                window.location = '{{ url('_some_other_route') }}';
            })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the assets are not correctly installed in the non-dev version ?

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything started working once I removed "true"...